# How to include a .jar dependency into the ANT target that generate my final .jar file of my application?

Tags: java, ant, jar, build

I am pretty new in Ant and I have the following problem creating the **build.xml** file that handle the creation of a **.jar** file of the following single class application:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World !!!");

        System.out.println(args.length);

        if(args.length != 0) {
            String partitaIVA = args[0];
            String nomePDF = args[1];
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement  stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2");
            TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);

            // Step 1: Allocate a database "Connection" object
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521:eme1", "myUserName", "myPswd");    // Oracle DB driver 

            System.out.println("After obtained connection with DB");

        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the behavior of the **main()** method is very simple, at this time only obtain a **connection with an Oracle database** (represented by the **Connection conn** object).

To obtain the connection it use this class **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver** that represent the Oracle DB Driver. This class is contained into a jar file named **ojdbc6.jar** that is putted inside the **lib** folder of my project.

So I have the following project structure:

```
**edi-sta** (the project root)
     |
     |----> **lib**
     |         |
     |         |-------> **ojdbc6.jar**
     |
     |----> **src**
     |         |
     |         |-------> **Main.java**
     |
     |----> **build.xml**
```

So I created this **build.xml** file:

```
<project name="edi-sta">

    <description>
        EDI-STA
    </description>

    <!-- ========================================================================= -->
    <!-- === Project Paths ======================================================= -->
    <!-- ========================================================================= -->

    <property name="project.base.dir" value="."/>

    <!-- ========================================================================= -->
    <!-- === DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE ========================================= -->
    <!-- ========================================================================= -->
    <!-- === Library Names ======================================================= -->
    <!-- ========================================================================= -->

    <property name="libname.ojdbc6" value="ojdbc6.jar"/>  <!-- JDBC DRIVER FOR ORACLE DB -->

    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- =========================== Classpath ============================= -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <fileset id="classpath.jars" dir="${project.base.dir}/lib">
        <include name="${libname.ojdbc6}" />
    </fileset>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>

        <echo>INTO compile TASK</echo>

        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" />

    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/Main.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./lib/ojdbc6.jar"/>
            </manifest>

        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="build/jar/Main.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

The problem is that, at this stage, when I try to execute my **Main.jar** in the console I obtain a **ClassNotFoundException**, in this way:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\build\jar>java -jar Main.jar
Hello World !!!
0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Unknown Source)

C:\Projects\edi-sta\build\jar>
```

This happens because I don't know how correctly include the **ojdbc6.jar** (the file that contains the Oracle driver **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**).

So I think that I have to do it into the **jar** target and so I have prepared a **fieldset** having **id="classpath.jars"** in which I putted the **ojdbc6.jar**.

But now what have I to do to use it to solve my problem? What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458761/how-to-include-a-jar-dependency-into-the-ant-target-that-generate-my-final-jar  Very annoying

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over again. The recommended way is to refine your current question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you're asking is how do I package one jar file into another, you should not do this (for many reasons, one being it is against almost all licenses).

When you run you compile **AND** when you run, you need the jdbc jar on your classpath:

Run with:

```
java -cp ./lib/ojdbc6.jar -jar Main.jar
```

or something like

```
java -cp Main.jar:./lib/ojdbc6.jar Main
```

Your `run` target in your build.xml also needs to reference the classpath.