# Running java file in cmd - error given

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I recently moved a project from one machine to another but I am now given an error when attempting to run java files on the new machine. I'm trying to run a java file from part of an Android project in command prompt but I am given an error. The file compiles okay but fails to run. Here is the error I am given;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ChatServer (
e: edu/UTEP/android/ChatServer)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas why I am receiving this error?

Comment: How are you running your Java file ? Can you add the command ?

Comment: I am running `Javac ChatServer.java` which compiles fine and then `Java ChatServer` to run and given this error.

Comment: I just posted my answer, you can do any of those two to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ChatServer` is having a package declaration of `edu.UTEP.android` in the top. So either you need to remove that package declaration recompile your java file again and run it

(or)

you need to create folder structure like this

```
CurrentDir/edu/UTEP/android/
```

Keep your java file in android folder and invoke `java ChatServer` from CurrentDir. Any of these two will solve the issue :-)

For more info on packages, you can refer to my previous answer on a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483236/why-if-i-try-to-execute-a-class-containing-the-main-method-from-within-its-pac/28484967#28484967)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .jar that provides ChatServer is in your runtime Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This issue rise when jvm don't file class path.
check where u have placed your jar file or lib folder.
Move to that directory then run javac and then java .
Issue will be resolved.