# Running Java on Linux with Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, classpath, command-line-arguments, jvm-arguments

I am getting the above error and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) isn't helping.

Basically I can't seem to run a file that I have compiled in Java. The file I am trying to run HowMARK_II_FitsInBrainAnatomy.java is [here](https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ/blob/master/experiments/model/MARK_II/vision/HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java)

I am using the following command to compile all needed .jars and the current directory with `:.` in the `-cp` argument at the end:

`javac -cp /home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/build/libs/WalnutiQ.jar:/home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/referencedLibraries/gson-2.2.4.jar:. HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java`

So after I use the above command I create the compiled file `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.class` but the the following command to run the file gives me the ERROR in the title of this question:

`java -cp /home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/build/libs/WalnutiQ.jar:/home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/referencedLibraries/gson-2.2.4.jar:. model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy`

I don't see what I am doing wrong as I add `:.` to my `-cp`

Comment: Please post `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java`

Comment: The links to your code are broken...

Comment: Yup.. links are broken but I just posted my answer explaining the issue. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Package names are not just pretty; they're where java will look for the class.  If your class is named `model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy` it must live in `model/MARK_II/vision/` within a classpath directory or JAR file.  If it doesn't, you need to restructure your source directory or build with the -d option to place the class in the expected location.

Comment: Please award the bounty so that this question stops showing up under the [Featured Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?&sort=featured).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say,

```
java -cp jars-to-add:. model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy
```

As your class has package declaration like this

```
package model.MARK_II.vision;
```

you need to use the Fully Qualified Class Name to invoke the `main()` in that class which you're doing already but also need to execute the command from correct directory.

I think you're already inside your `model/MARK_II/vision` directory when you're invoking this `javac` command, you need to come out of this directory and execute the command from a directory which has all these directories something like below

```
DirectoryToExecute
    --model
       --MARK_II
        --vision
          --HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.class
```

So I suggest you `cd` to that directory and then invoke the above command, then it will work :)

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483236/why-if-i-try-to-execute-a-class-containing-the-main-method-from-within-its-pac/28484967#28484967) on a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

if `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy` is in `model.MARK_II.vision` package, file `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.class` has to be in `model/MARK_II/vision` directory in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy` isn't normal executable class, but a *JUnit test case*. To run a JUnit test case from the command line you can use the `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` class.

Compile

```
javac -cp build/libs/WalnutiQ-master.jar:referencedLibraries/junit-4.12.jar:referencedLibraries/gson-2.2.4.jar:. experiments/model/MARK_II/vision/HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java
```

And run

```
java -cp build/libs/WalnutiQ-master.jar:referencedLibraries/junit-4.12.jar:referencedLibraries/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar:referencedLibraries/gson-2.2.4.jar:experiments/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy
```

I ran these from the root of your project from GitHub. I had to download JUnit and Hamcrest manually

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your class is

```
package model.MARK_II.vision;
```

That means you must specify the fully-qualified name to run it.

```
java -cp /home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/build/libs/WalnutiQ.jar:/home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/referencedLibraries/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/experiments/model/MARK_II/vision/junit-4.11.jar:. model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy
```

Of course, it will also need a method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

as an entry-point.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am just getting `Error: Could not find or load main class model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy
`

Comment: Add the `main` method, or it won't be a `main` class.

Comment: After I read your answer I did do that you can see in line 30 [here](https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ/blob/feature-issue_169/experiments/model/MARK_II/vision/HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java)

Comment: Did you recompile? And recreate your jar?

Comment: Good idea but I recompiled my jars and am still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

When running with `java`, you must specify the fully qualified name (ie, with the package). So if the class you want to run is `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy` and its package is `model.MARK_II.vision`, then you'd have to run:

```
java -cp <...> model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am just getting `Error: Could not find or load main class model.MARK_II.vision.HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy
`

Comment: Do you have a method with signature `public static void main(String[] args)`?

Comment: Ya I have it on line 30 [here](https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ/blob/feature-issue_169/experiments/model/MARK_II/vision/HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your compile command from

```
javac -cp <the jars>:. HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java
```

to

```
javac -cp <the jars>:. -d . HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java
```

This will create the `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.class` in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command-line suggests that the class to compile is in the current directory. Compiling it will produce a .class file in that same directory.

Now, when you try to run your program, you are perfectly right to pass the full name (package + class name) of the class to run ; but to find that class, java applies a convention stating that each segment of the package must correspond to a physical directory on the hard drive, starting from the current directory.

So instead of looking for your class in the current directory, it will try to look for a `model/MARK_II/vision/` directory tree, and for a file named `HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.class` there.

For your class to be found, you must set your current directory to the parent directory of `model`, still add `.` to your classpath (as it will be used as the root to find subdirectories) and keep your command line as-is (perhaps adjusting the paths to the additional jars as required).